# Is it possible to sell cars in single player?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Are you able to sell cars offline? I have tried with all different types of cars but it won't let me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cars cannot be sold in the single player game.

I've tried selling at LS Custom, but there is no option for it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Hopefully they add the ability into gta 6.